# Meteor session and router not working together

Tags: meteor

Meteor session and router not working together.when we click on the button not navigated to the pages.
As shown bellow the code.

```
getfamilys: function getfamilys(keyVal,searchitem, callback)
                  {
                    var familysArray = [];                      

                    familysArray = family.find({ },  {limit:10,skip:(Number(keyVal))}).fetch();

                     return familysArray;
                  }
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
"Exception from Tracker recompute function: Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids
LocalCollection._idStringify@http://localhost:4000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1114:11
seqChangedToArray/seqArray<@http://localhost:4000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:311:20
_.collect@http://localhost:4000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:174:1
seqChangedToArray@http://localhost:4000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:295:18
ObserveSequence.observe/computation</<@http://localhost:4000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:137:22
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:4000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:513:12
ObserveSequence.observe/computation<@http://localhost:4000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:121:7
Tracker.Computation.prototype._comput"[…]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please share the code. It's difficult to guess what's wrong without looking at the code.

Comment: You've edited the answer, is it the exact code you're using? You have a `searchitem` variable. Where is that used? Also are you sure `keyVal` is a number and not a string?

Answer (score 1):

First off you've not given any code so I can't give you any specific help to the problem. But the issue you have comes from trying to use something odd as an `_id` when you look for document changes.

In your code you're trying to process a document somewhere but you're not using a proper `_id` field.

You're doing something like this `xxx.find({_id: foo})` (or similar)

The issue is that your `foo` is not a String or a Mongo.ObjectID. Simply change change it to the string you're looking for and the problem should fix itself.